# Convergence of rivers of numbers

Tags: integer-sequences

$\DeclareMathOperator{\river}{river}\DeclareMathOperator{\leadingsum}{ls}\DeclareMathOperator{\digitsum}{ds}\newcommand{\qed}{\square}
$A [1999 British Informatics Olympiad question](https://www.olympiad.org.uk/papers/1999/bio/bio99r1q1.html) asks about recursively-defined integer sequences called **(digital) rivers**. In any sequence, the number following $n$ is $n$ plus the digit sum of $n$ (in base $10$). By $\river k$, we mean the sequence with first term $k > 0$. Two rivers **meet** when they have terms in common. (All formalised below in case you care.)

Let's consider $\river 173$ for example. After $173$ comes $173+1+7+3=184$, after $184$ comes $184+1+8+4=197$, after $197$ comes $197 + 1 + 9 + 7 = 214$, and so on.

We find that $\river 91 = (91, 101, 103, \dotsc)$ meets $\river 100=(100, 101, 103, \dotsc)$, and that they both meet $\river 173$.

The question asserts the following without proof (and does not ask candidates for a proof).

> **Claim:** All rivers eventually meet $\river 1$, $\river 3$ or $\river 9$.

We'll agree to call these three the **main rivers**. (One may calculate that $\river 173$, $\river 91$ and $\river 100$ all meet $\river 1$). My attempts to write a proof of the claim have yielded only partial progress (details below). I've asked others in my department to no avail and so I'm casting the net wider.

I am grateful for any insight you can shed and any literature references you may think relevant. I am equally content to see this attacked with elementary tools as with sledgehammers. I also include an alternative characterisation of "$n$ plus the digit sum of $n$", in case it helps. Many thanks in advance!

---

For the avoidance of doubt, here are some formal definitions.

Any positive integer $n$ has a unique base-$10$ representation $ \sum_{j=0}^\infty 10^j a_j $, where each $a_j \in \{0,1,2, \dotsc, 9\}$. In this representation, the **digit sum** of $n$ is $\digitsum n \mathrel{:=} \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j$. (The digit sum is not to be confused with what others call the "digital root".) We define $f(n) \mathrel{:=} n + \digitsum n$, and then $\river k \mathrel{:=} (f^k(n))_{k \geq 0}$.

We say $\river k $ meets $\river k' $ if there exist $J,J' \geq 0$ with $f^J(k)=f^{J'}(k')$.

---

The following simple argument shows that $\river 1$, $\river 3$ and $\river 9$ are distinct (and any river meets at most one of them). Recall that the doubling map $x \mapsto 2x \pmod 9$ on $\{1,2,\dotsc,9\}$ permutes elements as follows: $9 \mapsto 9$, $3 \mapsto 6 \mapsto 3$, $1 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 8 \mapsto 7 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 1$. Observe in particular that $1$, $3$ and $9$ lie on distinct cycles.

> ***Lemma 1.** $k \equiv \digitsum k \pmod 9 $.*
>
> *Proof 1.* $ k = \sum_{j=0}^\infty 10^j a_j \equiv \sum_{j=0}^\infty 1^j a_j =\sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_j = \digitsum k $. $\qed$

> ***Lemma 2.** $f(n) \equiv 2n \pmod 9$.*
>
> *Proof 2.* For any $j >0$, $f(n) = n + \digitsum n \equiv n + n = 2 n \pmod 9$ by Lemma 1. $\qed$

> ***Lemma 3.** The rivers $\river 1$, $\river 3$, $\river 9$ are distinct.*
>
> *Proof 3.* Reduce the entries of these rivers modulo $9$, and find that they are the periodic sequences $(1,2,4,8,7,5,1,\dotsc)$, $(3,6,3,\dotsc)$ or $(9,9,\dotsc)$, by Lemma 2. None shares any entries with another. $\qed$

Consequently, $\river k$ can meet at most one main river, depending on which cycle of the doubling permutation contains the residue of $k$ modulo $9$.

---

I'll end with an alternative characterisation of $f(n)$.

First, I need to define the number $\operatorname{tr} n$  of **trailing 9s** of $n$, which uses the base-$10$ representation of $n$ as above. Informally, it's the number of $9$s at the end of $n$, so that for example $\operatorname{tr} 78 = 0$, $\operatorname{tr} 79 = 1$, $\operatorname{tr} 99 = 2$, $\operatorname{tr} 7999 = 3$. Formally,
$$
\operatorname{tr}\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty 10^j a_j\right) \mathrel{:=} \max\{r \geq 0 \colon a_j = 9 \text{ for all } j \in \{0,1, \dots, r\}\}\text{.}
$$
Equivalently,
$$
\operatorname{tr} n \mathrel{:=} \max\{j \geq 0 \colon n+1 \text{ is a multiple of }10^j\}\text{.}
$$

> ***Lemma 4.** $\digitsum(n+1)-\digitsum n = 1 -9\operatorname{tr} n$.*
>
> *Proof 4.* What happens to the digits when we add $1$ to $n$? The rightmost non-$9$ digit is increased by $1$, and all the trailing $9$s to the right of it are reduced from $9$ to $0$. Remaining digits are unaffected. The result follows. $\qed$

> ***Lemma 5.** $f(n+1)-f(n) = 2-9\operatorname{tr} (n)$.*
>
> *Proof 5.* Follows trivially from Lemma 4. $\qed$

Next, define the **leading sum** of an integer $n>0$ to be $\leadingsum n \mathrel{:=} \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{10^j}\right\rfloor$ (beware: indices $j$ start at $1$, not $0$). Some examples: $\leadingsum 12345 = 1234 + 123 + 12 + 1 = 1370$ and $\leadingsum 173 = 17 + 3 = 20$.

> ***Lemma 6.** $ \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \operatorname{tr}(j) = \leadingsum(n)$.*
>
> *Proof 6.* There are $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor$ multiples of $10$ that are equal to or less than $n$ and each contributes $1$ to this sum. There are $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{100}\right\rfloor$ multiples of $100$ that are equal to or less than $n$ and each contributes a further $1$. Etc. The result follows. $\qed$

> ***Lemma 7.** $f(n) = 2n - 9\leadingsum n$.*
>
> *Proof 7.* We can form a telescoping sum
> $$f(n) - f(1) = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} f(j+1) - f(j) = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (2-9\operatorname{tr}j) = 2(n-1) - 9\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\operatorname{tr} j = 2(n-1) -9 \leadingsum n\text{.}$$
> To this, we simply add $f(1)=2$ and we're done. $\qed$

---

EDITS: typos

Comment: [River 1](http://oeis.org/A004207) and [river 3](http://oeis.org/A016052); OEIS does not know [river 9](http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C6%2C9%2C18%2C27%2C36%2C45%2C54%2C63%2C72%2C81%2C90%2C99%2C108%2C117&sort=&language=&go=Search), although it matches [A008591](http://oeis.org/search?q=9%2C+18%2C+27%2C+36%2C+45%2C+54%2C+63%2C+72%2C+81%2C+90%2C+99%2C+108%2C117%2C126%2C135%2C144%2C153%2C162%2C171%2C180%2C189&sort=&language=&go=Search) (multiples of 9) for a while, and, as you remark, is a subsequence of it, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Is it intentional that you include both 0 and 9 among the results of reduction modulo 9?

Comment: The slightly surprising thing is that river 1 and river 5 ([OEIS A007618](http://oeis.org/A007618)) do not meet until $620$ despite the small digitsum additions

Comment: Related to [self numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_number).

Comment: @LSpice No it was a mistake haha, thanks for spotting! I've edited the post to clarify that I only want remainders in {1, 2, ..., 9}. (I've also corrected the second formulation of $ \operatorname{tr}$.)

Comment: There are many references given at the links found by @LSpice, perhaps the question is answered at one of them.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've picked through those OEIS entries and their linked pages as best I could over a protracted Sunday tea break. I can find the claim conjectured in several places. I can find an estimated value for the $m$th term of an arbitrary binary digital river. I can find many case studies demonstrating the existence and abundance of self-numbers (those numbers not of the form $f(n)$ for any $n$). But no breakthroughs yet </3

Comment: The base b generalization here is obvious. Related question that I don't see an immediate proof of : Given a base $b>1$ there is a finite list of rivers where any other river eventually meets them. In fact, I don't even see immediately how to prove there even exists such a $b$.

Comment: @JoshuaZ For general (integer) $b>1$, let's say $x,y\in\{1,2,\dots,b-1\}$ are *equivalent* if $2^a x \equiv 2^b y \pmod{b-1}$ for some $a,b\geq 0$. Take as representative of each resulting equivalence classes the smallest member. I conjecture the main digital rivers in base $b$ are those given by those representatives. These are $k \in \{1,3,9\}$ for $b=10$; $k\in\{1\}$ for $b=9$; $k\in\{1,5\}$ for $b=11$; $k\in\{1,3,7\}$ for $b=15$, for example. (Some calculations I've run support my conjecture.)

Comment: A small but probably worthwhile point, I think, is I'd probably rather frame the general claim for (integer) base $b>1$ as "$\operatorname{river}{x}$ meets $\operatorname{river}{y}$ iff $2^u x \equiv 2^v y \pmod{b-1}$ for some $u,v$" and say that meeting forms an equivalence relation with finitely many classes, as discussed in my previous comment, rather than necessarily focussing on the representative rivers with "smallest" first entry.

Comment: @JoshuaZ Apologies, there is a typo in my first reply to you that I cannot now correct. I should of course have defined equivalence by saying "$2^u x \equiv 2^v y \pmod{b-1}$ for some $u,v \geq 0$", rather than reusing $b$. Facepalm!

Comment: @LSpice  River 9 is [OEIS A016096](https://oeis.org/A016096) - your search had spurious 3,6,108